# Нужна помощь с манипуляцией URL адреса

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте.

Имеется файл **file.pdf** в корне сайта, и его если переместить в определенную папку, нужно чтобы при вводе url файл открывался буд-то так: **site.ru/file.pdf** как буд-то в корне сайта. Как это можно оптимизировано реализовать?

Спасибо всем заранее за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

Самое короткое решение (для всей папки, куда будут сложены PDF):

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ $1
```

Теперь все файлы из папки `folder` будут открываться в корне сайта.

Проверить: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

Comment: Спасибо, но не работает. И было бы лучше, если только сам .pdf файл как в корне открывался находясь в папке.

Comment: Странно, что не работает. У вас что-то еще в htaccess стоит? Название папки поменяли на нужное?

Comment: Конечно поменял. Значит в корне сайта лежит папка к примеру "papka" а также .htaccess, я в нем прописал то что вы дали. Но после этого перестал открывать все файлы которые лежат в папке.

Answer (score 0):

Если ты об этом

Например у тебя в корне лежит `file.php`  который что-то генерирует ты хочешь его отдавать в адресе как `file.pdf`

то в  `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^file.pdf$ /file.php [L]
```

не забудь в самом начале `file.php` прописать заголовок `Content-type`

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
```

Comment: Вопрос немного не о том, читайте внимательнее :)